# US 2,038,852 A (April 1936) - Who was the manufacturer?

Tags: expired-patent, assignment-history, us2038852

[US 2,038,852 A](http://www.google.com/patents/US2038852)

This is a kitchen sink strainer system. How do I find out the manufacturer or supplier of this patent or find out if the product is still manufactured?

Answer (score 0):

For a patent that old, you will probably be able to find the information in the [*Official Gazette of the United States Patent Office*](https://archive.org/search.php?query=creator%3A%22United%20States.%20Patent%20Office%22). Look for "Abram N Pasman, assignor to" in association with the patent number and title, "2,038,852 Sink strainer".

There is no guarantee that the invention was ever manufactured and sold, but the assignor is the place to start.

After a patent has expired (I think 1948 in this case), the product should no longer be manufactured with the patent mark, and anyone may then produce the invention without licensing it from the inventor.

Comment: i have an older home and the kitchen sink has this patent mark stamped in the metal.  i am trying to find a replacement for the kitchen sink strainer basket and am trying to find a place to start looking.

Comment: @user15022R  I did a Google search on the inventor's name and also looked for sink manufacturers located in Milford, Ct. where the inventor is from. I came up with nothing. Perhaps you could perform a Google image search on sink strainers to see if you can find one that looks like yours. Otherwise you might try a different SE site such as http://diy.stackexchange.com. It might be possible to repair your strainer. There really is nothing else we here at patents can help you with.

Answer (score 0):

(This is obviously for the benefit of future readers who are wondering how to find ancient products with patent numbers imprinted on them.)

I read the application and I would suggest that you find a sheet metal fabricator in your area and have one fabricated for you. I suspect that some of the smaller parts, other than the strainer itself, can either be salvaged from your existing strainer or readily fabricated.

One of the key advantages of the patent system is that an application must "teach" someone ordinarily skilled in the art how to make the thing. Some of the actual fabrication methods may have changed over the past 80 years, but I believe an ordinarily skilled sheet metal fabricator could easily construct this object.

Turning now to the present invention, I suspect it stopped being relevant when the garbage disposal come into use. One possible motivation for this particular device was the ability to capture a larger amount of material. The inventor could have devised a device which solved the problems he identified within the application, but instead he devised an improved device which allowed not only operation in any orientation within the drain, but which obviously allowed a larger amount of material to be removed when the strainer itself was lifted out of the drain pipe. Unless you have a reason to retain that particular device, I'd suggest you follow the trail of innovation -- which is why we have the patent system: to foster innovation in the arts and sciences.

Answer (score -1):

I have one I found in the woods around my house where there user to be other houses long ago... made April 1936...

Comment: I fixed your many misspellings (you seem to type "q" when you want "a"). I don't think this is helpful to the original questioner unless you can indicate where it is manufactured.